# Building an In-car audio system using a Raspberry Pi

Tags: audio, bluetooth

My current car has a small Bluetooth Adapter for playing music though my cars AUX port, but its not great. I am currently looking at the idea of building a Raspberry Pi based version of this. I found the [following instructables article](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-Raspberry-Pi-into-a-Portable-Bluetooth-A/) showing how to get the Pi to act as a Bluetooth audio device, but i have a question:

- Has anyone done anything similar and have suggestions?
- Can the Pi send "messages" back to the phone?

For the second question, if i hook up a small keyboard or mouse to the Pi, hitting a particular button would be the equivalent of sending play/pause, back, forward, etc, to the phone. the current in car system has a small remote on the steering wheel, which is based on RF, and unless it can be hacked, i don't think this can be used. I would like to be able to use some sort of remote, not necessarily the one that i currently have, to control the phone.

Comment: You are not new at SE Q&A. You should know by now to ask a specific question and not a series of brain farts. Also  provide as many details as possible- we have no idea what kind of remote thing you are using.. Try using the search function for specific things. There is a wealth of information out here and there.

Comment: I have an RF Remote with the existing in car system, but i am pretty sure it wont work. I am looking for ANY remote that would work... I agree, i should have tweaked the question a bit better, but it was a quick "Brain fart" as you say to try get an idea out...

Comment: Hehehe. Just rephrase the question/questions and add some more details. I thought you wanted yo use the remote.. but you meant you have one and would like something like it? Yea.. Sometimes those RF remotes have public/ reverse engineered signals on line that can be intercepted by the PI using a 433mhz/900mhz receiver. So try and get the details of it.

Comment: ANy luck with this? :)

Comment: Might be looking into the new PiFM stuff: http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter

Comment: I will try out the Fm option, but have never had luck with Fm transmissions and my cars (BMW's all seem to have problems with transmissions from inside the car... Probably the size or something...)

Comment: Would an IR receiver suffice? http://ozzmaker.com/2013/10/24/how-to-control-the-gpio-on-a-raspberry-pi-with-an-ir-remote/

Answer (score 1):

1. [Yes - A lot of people have done or are trying to do similar stuff.](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=bluetooth%20audio)
2. Yes. Using Bluetooth SPP (RFCOMM) profile. It works really well and can run beside A2DP. You can send messages to and from.
3. If you want to use the remote try asking about that at [Electronics.StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) . If you want to use a keyboard to emulate the remote then look at answer 2.